# Facing issue with LDAP configuration

Tags: ldap

I have Mac OS 10.15.6, and I have installed OpenLDAP version 2.4.53 via brew
Whenever I run the below command:
ldapadd -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -f $DCM4CHEE_ARC/ldap/slapd/dicom.ldif

I get the below error:
ldap_sasl_interactive_bind_s: Can't contact LDAP server (-1)

My slapd.conf is pasted below:

```
#
# See slapd.conf(5) for details on configuration options.
# This file should NOT be world readable.
#
include         /private/etc/openldap/schema/core.schema
include   /etc/openldap/schema/dicom.schema
include   /etc/openldap/schema/dcm4che.schema
include   /etc/openldap/schema/dcm4chee-archive.schema
include   /etc/openldap/schema/dcm4chee-archive-ui.schema

# Define global ACLs to disable default read access.

# Do not enable referrals until AFTER you have a working directory
# service AND an understanding of referrals.
#referral       ldap://root.openldap.org

pidfile         /private/var/db/openldap/run/slapd.pid
argsfile        /private/var/db/openldap/run/slapd.args

# Load dynamic backend modules:
# modulepath    /usr/libexec/openldap
# moduleload    back_bdb.la
# moduleload    back_hdb.la
# moduleload    back_ldap.la

# Sample security restrictions
#       Require integrity protection (prevent hijacking)
#       Require 112-bit (3DES or better) encryption for updates
#       Require 63-bit encryption for simple bind
# security ssf=1 update_ssf=112 simple_bind=64

# Sample access control policy:
#       Root DSE: allow anyone to read it
#       Subschema (sub)entry DSE: allow anyone to read it
#       Other DSEs:
#               Allow self write access
#               Allow authenticated users read access
#               Allow anonymous users to authenticate
#       Directives needed to implement policy:
# access to dn.base="" by * read
# access to dn.base="cn=Subschema" by * read
# access to *
#       by self write
#       by users read
#       by anonymous auth
#
# if no access controls are present, the default policy
# allows anyone and everyone to read anything but restricts
# updates to rootdn.  (e.g., "access to * by * read")
#
# rootdn can always read and write EVERYTHING!

#######################################################################
# BDB database definitions
#######################################################################

database        bdb
suffix          "dc=dcm4che,dc=org"
rootdn          "cn=admin,dc=dcm4che,dc=org"
# Cleartext passwords, especially for the rootdn, should
# be avoid.  See slappasswd(8) and slapd.conf(5) for details.
# Use of strong authentication encouraged.
rootpw          secret
# The database directory MUST exist prior to running slapd AND
# should only be accessible by the slapd and slap tools.
# Mode 700 recommended.
directory       /private/var/db/openldap/openldap-data
# Indices to maintain
index   objectClass     eq
```

Please help.

Comment: I wonder if you could take a moment to read the instructions on formatting code samples, and then edit your question? It's almost unreadable at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

The command you are trying to use uses SASL to connect, which does not work. Instead try this:

```
$ ldapadd -x -D "cn=admin,dc=dcm4che,dc=org" -W -H ldapi:/// -f $DCM4CHEE_ARC/ldap/slapd/dicom.ldif
```

Per your slapd.conf the password should be secret.

Before you run the above make sure that slapd is up and running.